# CSS Dropdown Menu dropping horizontally

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu

I'm working on a website that was built several years ago by my employer, and I'm trying to implement a dropdown menu using CSS only. However, instead of dropping *down* when you hover over it, it drops *horizontally*, like so:

[image]

It also loses all the formatting of the parent list, even though I suspect something in the parent CSS is overwriting what I'm trying to do.

What am I missing/overwriting?

HTML

```
    <div id="main_nav_container"> 
  <ul id="main_nav_list">
        <li><a class="main_nav_item" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="main_nav_item" href="history.html">History</a></li>
        <li><a class="main_nav_item" href="products.html">Products</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        <li><a class="main_nav_item" href="news.html">News</a></li>
        <li><a class="main_nav_item" href="links.html">Links</a></li>
        <li><a class="main_nav_item" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#main_nav_list a.main_nav_active_item {
 background: url(images/dynamic/buttonset1/n1activeitem.gif) no-repeat;
 font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
 font-style: normal;
 font-size: 11px;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff7de;
  }
#main_nav_list a.main_nav_item {
 background: url(images/dynamic/buttonset1/n1.gif) no-repeat;
 font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
 font-style: normal;
 font-size: 11px;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff7de;
  }
#main_nav_list a.main_nav_item:hover {
 background: url(images/dynamic/buttonset1/n1hover.gif) no-repeat;
 font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
 font-style: normal;
 font-size: 11px;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff7de;
  }

ul ul{
 display: none;
 list-style: none;
 float: left;
  }
ul> li > ul:hover {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
  }
```

Comment: looks like you need `position:relative` on the parent `li` and some `top, left` values to make it look nice.

Comment: You are not closing your li

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/66esagLq/

Looks like you're missing a `</li>` in your html:

```
 <div id="main_nav_container"> 
  <ul id="main_nav_list">
        <li><a class="main_nav_item" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="main_nav_item" href="history.html">History</a></li>
        <li><a class="main_nav_item" href="products.html">Products</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li> <!-- here -->
        <li><a class="main_nav_item" href="news.html">News</a></li>
        <li><a class="main_nav_item" href="links.html">Links</a></li>
        <li><a class="main_nav_item" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <ul>
</div>
```

Additionally:

```
ul> li:hover > ul {
     position: absolute;
     display: block;
}
```

I wanted to make sure this worked, so I made a minor change to the fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/66esagLq/1/

Adding these CSS rules:

```
ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
ul ul li {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: `</li>` end tags are optional. Are you sure this has a different result than the OP's source?

Comment: @MrLister they are optional in SOME cases, not all. "An li element's end tag may be omitted if the li element is immediately followed by another li element or if there is no more content in the parent element.  "[see here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/syntax.html#optional-tags)

Comment: I don't know any valid html that would compile properly missing a `</li>`, but I also made a small css change that fixed it and added a jsfiddle.

Comment: @CBauer I copied everything you changed, and it works in the fiddle and looks great, but still drops horizontally in my document. So it looks like there's something in the previous css or the linked javascript overwriting it? I've combed through my css and haven't found the problem. Any ideas on what I'm looking for?

Comment: You would have to post all of your CSS for me to answer that. Ideally you would do so in the jsfiddle I provided and make the issue reproducible. Also, this is probably a CSS specificity issue. You could use a built-in browser tool and check what css rules are being overridden.